# MacOS Anaconda caused warning messages on Powerlevel 10k with Zsh

Tags: anaconda, zsh, oh-my-zsh, anaconda3

I have been using Powerlevel 10k with Zsh on *MacOS Monterey*.

Now that I've just installed Anaconda for MacOS, whenever I open a new tab in the terminal iTerm, I get the following message:

```bash
[WARNING]: Console output during zsh initialization detected.

When using Powerlevel10k with instant prompt, console output during zsh
initialization may indicate issues.

You can:

  - Recommended: Change ~/.zshrc so that it does not perform console I/O
    after the instant prompt preamble. See the link below for details.

    * You will not see this error message again.
    * Zsh will start quickly and prompt will update smoothly.

  - Suppress this warning either by running p10k configure or by manually
    defining the following parameter:

      typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=quiet

    * You will not see this error message again.
    * Zsh will start quickly but prompt will jump down after initialization.

  - Disable instant prompt either by running p10k configure or by manually
    defining the following parameter:

      typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=off

    * You will not see this error message again.
    * Zsh will start slowly.

  - Do nothing.

    * You will see this error message every time you start zsh.
    * Zsh will start quickly but prompt will jump down after initialization.

For details, see:
https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#instant-prompt

-- console output produced during zsh initialization follows --

(eval):13: unmatched "
```

I have tried:

```
conda config --set changeps1 false
```

But it didn't work.

How do I fix it?

**Aparently solved**

As stated in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/jc48a7/comment/g8zbxj0/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), I have tried:

Open the .zsh config:

```
❯ nvim ~/.zshrc
```

And at the top of the file, add the following line:

```
export CONDA_AUTO_ACTIVATE_BASE=false
```

Then reload the zsh config:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

And it seemed to work

Comment: Disabling auto-activation is not a fix - it's just going to be broken again when you actually need to activate an environment. `changeps1` set to false should be sufficient - maybe you hadn't restarted the shell? There's also the `env_prompt` setting (see `conda config --describe env_prompt`)

Answer (score 0):

I had same warning because, in my file **"~/.zshrc"**

At the last line I had :

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
source <(ng completion script)
```

After i remove it the warning has disappeared, hope it can help you